# SQLite error: foreign key mismatch when I try to make an INSERT command

Tags: sqlite, table

I'm trying to create an **Associative Entity** (N:N) in SQLite like this:

> [ Pet ---< VaccinePet >--- Vaccine ]

And, I have the follow code of my associative entity:

```
CREATE TABLE  VACINAPET (
        vp_date TEXT NOT NULL,
        vp_is_applied INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        fk_pet INTEGER,
        fk_vaccine INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_pet) REFERENCES pet (pet_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_vaccine) REFERENCES vaccine (vaccine_id),
        PRIMARY KEY (fk_pet, fk_vaccine) 
);
```

BUT, I'm getting an error:

> foreign key mismatch - "VACCINEPET" referencing "vaccine": INSERT INTO
>   VACCINEPET (vp_date, vp_is_applied, fk_pet, fk_vaccine) VALUES
>   ('23/05/2018', 0, 1, 1);

When I try to use the INSERT command:

> INSERT INTO VACINAPET (vp_data, vp_is_aplicada, fk_pet, fk_vacina)
>   VALUES ('23/05/2018', 0, 1, 1);

What could be wrong? I'm not so good in database... :(

MASTER DETAIL: I have data in **Pet** table and **Vaccine** table, they are not empty

Comment: Your insert statement seems to be in Spanish or similar, so I assume that's not the actual statement for the table as given here? Anyway, do you have records in the Pet and Vaccine tables each with primary key values of 1? What are the data types of these primary keys? And are they perhaps defined as NOT NULL? It would probably help to see the CREATE statements for both these tables.

Answer (score 4):

The error message "foreign key mismatch" does *not* indicate a constraint violation, but that your database schema is wrong.

Assuming that the `vaccine` table and the `vaccine_id` column actually exist, the most likely reason is that the [required index](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) is missing, i.e., that `vaccine_id` is not the primary key (or at least unique).